# Browser zoom and elements width

Tags: html, css, position

I have a line in my design, my content has a `width: 1200px`, but I want to make this line has `width: 100%`, relative to screen, e.g. when user resize (using browser zoom) screen, make it smaller this line need to still have `width: 100%`, the other elements will stay with `width: 1200px`, and it works, but when I zoom screen to make elements bigger (zoom 130%) the line makes smaller and when I user scrollbar to scroll into right part of screen the line ripped. Here is the styles of the line:

```
#blue_line {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
left: 0;
right: 0;
height: 5px;
background-color: #08c5ef;
z-index: 20;
```

}

If it nessasery I can post fiddle. Thanks!

Comment: fiddle online https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=UfRfO8yBd6

Comment: Does the line need to be inside the wrapper? if so, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, using vh (viewport height) on the height should fix this for you.

```
#blue_line {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 1vh;
    background-color: #08c5ef;
    z-index: 20;
}
```

Comment: hm, nope this does not help, maybe I need to post my answer more clearly?

Comment: Accordingly to my best knowledge `vh` unit means viewport height, not vertical height, same as `vw` is viewport width.